# Тестирование входящих аргументов мокируемого метода в laravel

Tags: laravel, тестирование, phpunit, laravel-9

В приложении на laravel создан сервисный слой, отвечающий за взаимодействие с внешним сервисом.

Я хочу протестировать его с помощью частичной подмены методов, осуществляющих непосредственную отправку подготовленного запроса (всего таких методов 4, запрос осуществляется на один адрес), используя partialMock():

```
        $this->partialMock(SomeService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('sendHttpRequest')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn('fake');
        });


        $bbService = resolve(SomeService::class);
        $bbService->sendRequest();
    }
```

этот код прекрасно работает:

- метод once() проверяет, что подставной метод SomeService::sendHttpRequest() вызывается ровно один раз;
- метод andReturn() возвращает фейковый ответ 'fake', что позволяет мне проверить логику класса без необходимости получения ответа от стороннего сервиса.

Но мне также необходимо проверить корректное формирование строки запроса. Насколько я понял за проверку входящих параметров отвечает метод with():

```
        $this->partialMock(SomeService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('sendHttpRequest')
                ->once()
                ->with($this->equalTo('some string'))
                ->andReturn('fake');
        });


        $bbService = resolve(SomeService::class);
        $bbService->sendRequest();
    }
```

Но после добавления *->with($this->equalTo('some string'))* стал игнорироваться метод andReturn(), и вместо подмены вызывается метод SomeService::sendHttpRequest()

```
    // SomeService class

    /**
     * Получение ответа на запрос метода file
     * Метод объявлен публичным для частичной имитации при тестировании
     *
     * @param string $xmlBody
     * @return string
     */
    public function sendHttpRequest(string $xmlBody): string
    {
        // проверка вызова оригинального метода вместо подставного
        return 'original';


        $httpResponse = $this->sendRequest('file', $xmlBody);


        return $httpResponse->body();
    }


    public function send(): void
    {
        ...

        $xmlBody = $this->getXml($message);
        $bodyHttpResponse = $this->sendHttpRequest($xmlBody);
        dd($bodyHttpResponse);

        ...
    }
```

без метода with() в терминале выводится "fake", при добавлении метода with() - выводится "original".

Что я делаю не так? Есть возможность проверить входящие данные мокируемого метода без его выполнения?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```
    $this->partialMock(SomeService::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $callback = function (string $yourParam) {
            $this->assertEquals($yourParam, 'YourCheckString');
        };

        $mock->shouldReceive('sendHttpRequest')
            ->once()
            ->andReturnUsing($callback);
    });
```